# Windows service / ASP site / something other?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, wcf, windows-services

I need to write something for listen data for devices like gps and other device that can send every X seconds me data

And I will can to add device to my database from web site / (via wcf service)

Now I want after I added new device to database I want to start get from device data.

I dont want to do it in wcf service - so I want top write a little program only for get data.

What is better way for get data in background ?
Also I will need sent "push notification" from WCF to this program - for add new device to list

So what is better way ? windows service /  console/wpf programm /  asp.net ??
Sorry for English grammar

Answer (score 1):

You can use either windows service or console application. I will suggest you to develop console application and configure it as schedule task. Schedule task is allow you to define task job to execute the console application.

Some advantages using console application over windows service:

1. Easy to debug/truobleshoot.
2. Easy to develop and configure.
3. No need to learn how to write Windows service.
4. Don't require extra permissions.